# How to handle disk cache while use Retrofit?

Tags: android, retrofit, diskcache

I wanna to cache my data which request by Retrofit,but i don't know how to implement it.

As we know read/write cache is time-consumed,and we should not do it in main thread.

Does anybody can tell me how should i do to cache my data with Retrofit?Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Retrofit itself doesn't cache your data. You can use orm libraries to do it without much work.

Lately I've used [Realm](http://realm.io/), that has a [section](http://realm.io/docs/java/0.80.0/#other-libraries) in their docs specifically for Retrofit.